# printf((char *) i); runtime error? (i as integer)

Tags: c++, runtime-error

In a for loop, I am trying to use printf to print the current i value.  This line: `printf((char *) i);` is giving me runtime errors.  Why is this?!

Below is a quick fizzbuzz solution that is doing this:

```
void FizzBuzz()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf((char *)i);
        if ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0))
        {
            printf("FizzBuzz \n");
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            printf("Fizz \n");
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            printf("Buzz \n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record, instead of doing `if((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0))` you could just do `if(i % 15 == 0)`.

Comment: This is true!  0 thought was put into this, it was just a generic example that everybody should hopefully be familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's not how `printf` works.  You want this instead:

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Or even better,

```
std::cout << i;
```

Comment: std::cout << i << std::endl; to write an exact equivalent of your printf line

Comment: This is definitely correct, but I'm sitll getting a runtime error and it breaks in dbghook.c..

Comment: std::cout isn't better than printf.  Just different.

Comment: Weird, another Chris commenting on this, haha.  I've edited my question with code.

Comment: `std::cout` is typesafe, and won't break on you with segfaults unless you pass it a real pointer (whereas `printf` will break if you write the format string improperly).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++, you should use cout instead of printf:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        int i = 42;
        cout << "The answer is: " << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: is "using namespace stdl" required for cout?  I tried using cout initially and my compiler did not recognize it, but i excluded that line.

Comment: You either do "using namespace std;" or write "std::cout << i << std::endl;" instead. Read about C++ namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

By that statement what you are telling is :"there is a sting starting at location i, display it " Surely that is not what you intended. Use format string %d to print a integer

Answer (score 2):

The way printf works is that it takes a string like this:

```
printf( "the number is: " );
```

If you then want an integer in the last section of the string you need to use an escape character and then pass the int in as another paramater:

```
printf( "the number is %d", i );
```

There is more information [here](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/c_Notes/tips_printf.html) on the escape characters you can use.

You will also need to include:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry my terminology was wrong, % followed by a sequence is called a **conversion specification** not an escape characer.

HTH.

Comment: `%d` is not what we commonly call an escape character (`\n`, etc.).

Comment: It's not called a "conversion specification", either, because nothing is converted by `printf` (if you pass it a `char*`, and tell it it's an `int` - e.g. `%d` - in the format string, you will get U.B.). It's called a "format specifier".

Comment: My link to some course notes at MIT called it a conversion specification and that sounded fine to me. Either way it certainly isn't an escape character!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `printf()` is a C-style null-terminated string.  It's meant to be used as a format (thus the "f") with `%` formatting sequences to print the remaining arguments.

By using `printf((char *) i);` you are instructing the computer to print every byte starting at the address that `i` points to, until it encounters a null.  Unfortunately, given that `i` is usually used for counters, it probably points to very low memory.  Most modern operating systems prohibit access to such memory from user-space programs to prevent bugs from creating security holes, and will send signals to offending programs.  The default response to such a signal, unless you trap it, is to kill the process.

To instead display the number stored in `i`, use `printf("%d\n", i);`.  To display the value of `i` as a character, try `putc((char)i);` or `printf("%c\n", i);`.  If `i` really is a pointer to a character, try `putc((char)(*i));`.